# Bayesian Optimization in Python makes more iterative than specified

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, bayesian, gaussian-process

I'm using Python [bayesian-optimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) to optimize an XGBoost model.

I specified the number of iteration as 10:

```
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
.
.
.

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
    f=my_xgb,
    pbounds=pbounds,
    verbose=2, 
    random_state=1,
)

optimizer.maximize(
    init_points=20,
    n_iter=10
)
```

When I ran the code I see that the number of iterations exceeds 10 and keeps running

[image]

Why is that?

My guess is that it has something to do with the `init_points` but I don't have an explanation for that.

Comment: It will do `init_points` + `n_iter` iterations. See the example in https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization.

Comment: Thanks, you inferred it from the examples, right? or is specified there?

Comment: There is a description with an example call with `optimizer.maximize(init_points=2,    n_iter=3,)` Please read carefully the page https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization